# encodeURIComponent() difference with browsers and [ä ö å] characters

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with `encodeURIComponent()` as it seems to behave differently than browsers (tested with Chrome and Firefox):

- `encodeURIComponent('ä')` returns `%C3%A4`
- `escape('ä')` returns `%E4`
- Chrome/Firefox encodes `ä` in x-www-form-urlencoded forms as `%E4`

So, why does `encodeURIComponent` behave differently than all the others (mainly browsers)? This actually causes problems as some websites don't understand what I'm trying to feed them. The website in question is http://verkkopalvelu.vrk.fi/Nimipalvelu/default.asp?L=1 (click "Etunimihaku" as it is iframe based).

Is `encodeURIComponent` broken and how should this situation be corrected? What would be the correct way to encode characters like `ä ö å`? `escape()` seems to encode the same as those browsers, but `escape()` is deprecated.

I tested the browsers with Fiddler and also the Console/Network tab shows the encoding as `%E4` when I submit a form. Also a test link here: A http://jsfiddle.net/tcyfktvg/1/

Comment: Will you accept my answer or comment, if it misses essential information?

Answer (score 3):

`encodeURIComponent()` is not broken. It encodes the chars using UTF-8 char set. Always. ([ECMAScript 3rd Edition (ECMA-262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) page 82)

`escape()` uses Unicode for encoding ([ECMAScript 1st Edition (ECMA-262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) page 60). If the unicode code is < 256 then the simple two letter representation is used, as you see for "ä". If the unicode code is >= 256, then the extended four char representation with a leading "u" is used. Example: `escape("겧") == "%uACA7"`.

The problem arises when a http server receives a encoded URL. It has to decode it. But the URL itself doesn't tell which encoding was used to create it.

This URL: `http://server/%C3%A4` could be a `http://server/ä` if it was encoded by `encodeURIComponent()` (using UTF-8), but it could also be a `http://server/Ã¤` encoded by `escape()` (using Unicode):

```
encodeUriComponent("ä") == "%C3%A4"
escape("Ã¤") == "%C3%A4"
```

It's up to the configuration of the server which encoding it will use to decode the URL. So here's the solution to your problem: know which URL encoding the http server expects and choose the appropriate encoding method.

Comment: In case you came here due to this annoying IIS issue (that an encoded string from javascript is wrongly decoded on server) check here for solution https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/6267#issuecomment-30159152